# PHP and jQuery display:none

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to display an error text using jQuery, when the username field is blank. This is not the problem, because I have done this already. The problem is that after the error text shows, I want to click the username field and hide the error text div, so that I can be able to reshow the error if the field is still blank using jQuery.

When I set the visibility to hidden in CSS using jQuery it automaticlly adds an `display: hidden` when I look at the code in Google Chrome's inspector.

The code is in: http://albsocial.net84.net/

```
<?php include ("php/head.php"); ?>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="container">

        <div id="intro">

            <h2><center>Are you a member? Login ...</center></h2>
            <h3><center>And enjoy hundreds of services.</center></h3>



            <div id="log_form">

                <form action="php/login.php" method="post" class="login_form">

                    <input type="text" size="25" name="log_uname"
                           id="login_txt" placeholder="Your Username">
                    <input type="password" size="25" name="log_password" id="login_pass" placeholder="Your Password">
                    <label id="check"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">         Remember Me</label>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit1" id="login_sub" value="LogIn">
                    <img id="loading1" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="working.." />



                    <script>
                        $('#login_txt').click(function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('#error1').fadeOut('fast', function () {
                                $(this).css("visibility","hidden");
                            });
                        });             
                    </script>

                </form>

                <div id="error1"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="new_users">
                <h4 class="h4_users">New Users ...</h4>

                <a href="#"><img src="#" width="55" height="55"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="#" width="55" height="55"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="#" width="55" height="55"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="#" width="55" height="55"></a>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="register">
            <h2><center>Sign up Below ...</center></h2>
            <h3><center>Easy, fast and free!</center></h3>

            <form action="php/register.php" method="post" name="form" class="form">
                <input type="text" size="25" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
                <input type="text" size="25" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
                <input type="text" size="25" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="text" size="25" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="text" size="25" name="email2" placeholder="Repeat Email">
                <input type="password" size="25" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="password" size="25" name="password2" placeholder="Repeat Password">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sub" value="Sign Up!">
                <img id="loading" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="working.." />
            </form>
            <div id="error"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php include("php/footer.php"); ?>
```

and the code im using to actually show or create the error code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.form').submit(function(e) {
        register();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('.login_form').submit(function(e) {
        login();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});

function register(){
    hideshow('loading',1);
    error(0);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/register.php",
        data: $('.form').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg){
            if(parseInt(msg.status)==1){
                window.location=msg.txt;
            } else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0) {
                error(1,msg.txt);
            }
            hideshow('loading',0);
        }
    });
}

function login(){
    hideshow1('loading1',1);
    error1(0);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/login.php",
        data: $('.login_form').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg1){
            if(parseInt(msg1.status1)==1){
                window.location=msg1.txt1;
            } else if (parseInt(msg1.status1) == 0) {
                error1(1,msg1.txt1);
            }
            hideshow1('loading1',0)
        }
    });
}
function hideshow(el,act){
    if(act) $('#'+el).css('visibility','visible');
    else $('#'+el).css('visibility','hidden');
}
function error(act,txt){
    hideshow('error',act);
    if(txt) $('#error').html(txt);
}
function hideshow1(el,act){
    if(act) $('#'+el).css('visibility','visible');
    else $('#'+el).css('visibility','hidden');
}
function error1(act,txt1){
    hideshow1('error1',act);
    if(txt1) $('#error1').html(txt1);
}
```

Comment: im actually trying the following code im even trying $(this).css("display","inline")  and its still not working please take a look at my site for more details http://albsocial.net84.net/

Comment: A div tag is a "block" element, not an "inline" element, so to make it visible you should do display:'block' and display:'none' to hide it.  By making a div "inline", you're basically turning it into a span tag. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('#error1').fadeOut('fast', function () {
   $(this).show()
   $(this).css("visibility","hidden")    
})
```

because fadeOut sets display:none; and you are also working with the visibility attribute, get rid of visibility and use .show() and .hide() instead

Comment: thank you very much man i appriciate everybodys help .. have a wonderful day .. IT WORKEDDD :)

Comment: mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem, and rewrite your code, don't use the visible attribute :P

Answer (score 0):

Doing a `.css('display', 'none');` and `.css('display', 'block')` to hide/show should work fine.

An alternative would be to set the `.html('')` to remove the text from within the div (thus causing it to hide).  Then you wouldn't need to worry about the visibility of the div.

Comment: thank you for answering but i dont think it would of worked because i need the value of #error1 = visibility: hidden;

Comment: Why do you need to use "visibility"?  I agree, that is strange behavior for jquery to turn it into "display", but setting the text to blank (and not worrying about visibility at all) seems like a much simpler solution that would allow you to remove some unneeded code.

Comment: i need to use visibility=hidden because if i dont when i click the sign in and if i leave a blank field for the second time the visibility will be visible which i would be fine if it didnt have display:none which it adds automaticlly please take a llok at my site and source code if you can before and after you click sign in and click the username field

Comment: What I'm saying is, you don't need to set ANY visibility on it.  Don't hide the div at all.  Just set the text within the div to blank when you want to hide it by calling .html('');.

Comment: thanks for your help but supernova's answer corrected my problem .. anyways thanks for taking your time looking at my code .. have a nice day